# <String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int' error

Tags: flutter

Im trying to code a weather app., i want to have small cards bottom of the screen that shows the user next 5 days weather data but i get this error

```
var temps = new List.filled(5, 0);
var abbrs = new List.filled(5, 0);

setState(() {
      weather = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][0]['the_temp'].round();

      for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        temps[i] = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][i + 1]['the_temp'].round();
        abbrs = abbrs[i] = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][i + 1];

        //  ['weather_state_abbr'];
      }

DailyWeather(
    date: 'Tuesday',
    temp: temps[1].toString(),
    image: abbrs[1].toString()),
```

Answer (score 1):

Its look like you assign string instead of int in somewhere.

```
var temps = new List.filled(5, 0);
var abbrs = new List.filled(5, 0);

setState(() {
      weather = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][0]['the_temp'].round();

      for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        temps[i] = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][i + 1]['the_temp'].round();
         // Check Here
        abbrs[i] = locationTempParsed['consolidated_weather'][i + 1];
      }

DailyWeather(
    date: 'Tuesday',
    temp: temps[1], // Check Here
    image: abbrs[1].toString()),
```